# WordPress Sandbox сайты с возможностью установить собственный код

Tags: wordpress, sandbox

Ищу бесплатный сайты (хостинги) песочниц где можно б было развернуть для теста фукционала сайт на `CMS WordPress`. Почему-то все, что удалось найти не дает возможности попасть в папку темы сайта `wp-content/themes` чтобы показать работу какой-то функции.
Что-то по тип:

- https://jsfiddle.net/
- [https://codesandbox.io/](https://codesandbox.io/s/?utm_source=landingpage)

Но для WordPress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый лучший из перебранных мной [https://tastewp.com](https://tastewp.com/a/site)

2 дня без реги, неделя после регистрации.
Есть "рецепты" - быстроразворачиваемые бекапы своих проектов.

Ограничения:

- 1гб на сайт
- Не работает mail(), но если нужно - можно через сторонние SMTP.

Т.к. нет доступа к ФТП, то "свой код" лучше испытывать через плагин типа [Code Snippets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/).
Но в случае чего - можно и из дашборда отключить все плагины.

Comment: Спасибо... странно но меня при создании нового сайта на данном хостинге мгновенно антивирус про заражение в сойдинении файла `usepancake.2s-tastewp.com` придупредил. и сбросил сойдинение. У вас такое было ?

Comment: @BlackStar1991 Никогда не было